# Any introduction on how to use sisu?

Tags: document

[sisu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/sisu) is an application for documents structuring, publishing in multiple formats and search.

I was wondering

1. How well it is received by users, and if there are other similar applications that are comparable to or even better than sisu；
2. if there is some introduction to
   show its functionality and how to
   use it;
3. if there is some GUI for it, as it
   is command line oriented?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the SiSu homepage itself has a very thorough document on using sisu: http://www.sisudoc.org/sisu/sisu_manual/sisu_intro.html